# Run-time Manifest-based events

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, event-log, etw

Does the fact that Manifest-based events are defined in resources mean that I can't generate the parameters (like Level, Message, EventID etc) at run-time without modifying the resources in binary?

Comment: AFAIK, yes. Manifests are static. Events in manifests cannot be changed dynamically. That would prevent event consumers from knowing what event data to expect.

Answer (score 0):

When you compile an event manifest, the strings go in the resources, but the event descriptors go into a header file, which gets compiled into your program.

You should be able to use the [Event Tracing Macros](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363797%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to alter a precompiled event descriptor.